# How to collect elements of a collection basing on a result of some method?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Suppose we have a list of values sorted according to some ordering. We also have a map of elements mapped to these values. We want to obtain a collection of elements from the map in the same order as their keys are in the list. A straightforward method to do this is:

```
val order = Seq("a", "b", "c")
val map = Map("a" -> "aaa", "c" -> "ccc")

val elems = order.map(map.get(_)).filter(_.isDefined).map(_.get)
```

However the program needs to iterate over the collection three times. Is it possible to implement this functionality more efficiently? In particular, is it possible to do this with *collect* method?

Comment: isDefined is only an example. I would like to use various methods for filtering. In other words I am looking for a way to do mapping-with-filtering with single iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally you can use views; then the collection is only iterated once and all three operations are applied as you go:

```
order.view.map(map.get).filter(_.isDefined).map(_.get).force
```

Comment: All of the solutions are great, however this one is the most versatile for me.

Answer (score 3):

Well, a standard Scala map is also a PartialFunction, so you can use "collect".

```
val elems = order.collect(map)
```

Comment: Ok, so what about some data source, where we have a method getById which returns Option?

Answer (score 2):

If you base it on an `Option` return, then this works:

```
order flatMap (map get)
```

Though, of course, `order collect map` is enough in this particular example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use flatMap for that. Here is an example:

```
List(1,2,3,4,5).flatMap(x => if (x%2 == 1) Some(2*x) else None)
```

This is equivalent to

```
List(1,2,3,4,5).filter(_%2==1).map(2*)
```